# I'm confused in my database

Tags: database, database-design

I want to really decide what the proper way of creating a database in the field of inventory is. I have this table `Product`, my product has `id`, `supplier`, `product_name`, `category`, `size`, `color`, `expiration` and `selling_price`.

So we create a UI that inputs 1 product but having many input sizes.

[image: The Picture here]

My first resort to input them in my product table is to loop them based on the sizes (my counter is how many sizes are to be inputted) because in 1 product there is only 1 size right?

For example I have a product named `Nike` that has sizes 11 12 13 and 14.
Since there are 4 sizes, I will loop them for 4 times in table product there should be 4 rows now, same product name but different sizes. It's not redundant since in 1 product there is only 1 size.

Now, I'm little bit confused. Nike can be or has many sizes but it 1 product can be 1 size in rule right? or brand? or what? so should I normalize and make another table named Product_sizes or just let it be? cause even if I'll make another table, there will always be 4 rows in respect for the sizes.

Help!

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question. Is this a database design question, for tracking inventory of shoes? The GUI screenshot doesn't help me understand anything. 

Please write just what details you are trying to track.

Thank you,

Comment: yes a database design question. do products have many sizes or 1 only? cause even if they have many sizes there can only be 1 foreign key in product_size column in my table product

Comment: The picture there shows the UI we create having many input of sizes in 1 product.

Comment: "Do products have many sizes or 1 only?" This is a question you need to answer for yourself. We cannot see the data set. Is there a unique product identifier for each size? What is common among multiple sizes of the same item? That is what determines how normalization should be done.

Answer (score 1):

From your text, I guess a proper database structure would be something like (please note that Nike sounds not like a product to me, but a supplier, so I include that here):

```
supplier(id, name, ...)
product(id, name, description, supplier_id, ...)
product_size(id, size, product_id, ...)
```

The point is to introduce a separate table for the sizes available for each particular product. Otherwise, introducing a product record for each size, you would introduce lots of redundancies, e.g. repeated product names and descriptions for each size, which will lead to consistency problems.

It's up to your specific requirements which attributes should go to product, and which to product size. If, e.g., the price will always be the same for all sizes of the same product, it goes to the product, otherwise to the size. The same even holds for the product no. If your client has separate product numbers for each size, they go to the size table, otherwise to the product. (This is not to be confused with the database id, which should be used in any case and be present for each of the tables.)

Don't get confused by the structure of a particular representation to the user. Even if you use the table design suggested above, you can still generate a list where each size is displayed as a product line of its own. Just don't *store* the data that way.